# Python Pandas - How to check a value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

How do I find a missing line in the dataframe and add a new one?

The DataFrame `df`

```
    federalState    hasParking  Size
0   A               False       154
1   A               True        531
2   B               False       191
3   B               True        725
4   C               True        54
5   D               False       100
6   D               True        656
```

For `df['federalState']` the false for `C` is missing

The final result should look like this

```
    federalState    hasParking  Size
0   A               False       154
1   A               True        531
2   B               False       191
3   B               True        725
4   C               False       89
5   C               True        54
6   D               False       100
7   D               True        656
```

My code for adding the new line

```
df.loc[-1] = ['C', 'False' , 89]  # adding a row
df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
df = too.sort_values(by=['federalState'])  # sorting by index
```

But how do I find out that the line is missing? My `if`-statement does not work

```
if ((df['federalState']=='C) and (df['hasParking']=='True')).any():
```

Comment: `'True'` is not the value you should be comparing to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For chain condition use `&` for `and`. If `hasParking` is boolean `== True` should be omit.

There is difference between `True` - as `boolean` and `'True'` as `string`, I think you need remove `''` because boolean column.

```
if ((data['federalState']=='C') & (data['hasParking'])).any():
#same as
#if ((data['federalState']=='C') & (data['hasParking'] == True)).any():
```

And for first is possible after sorting add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default `index`:

```
df.loc[-1] = ['C', False , 89]  # adding a row
df = df.sort_values(by=['federalState']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  federalState  hasParking  Size
0            A       False   154
1            A        True   531
2            B       False   191
3            B        True   725
4            C        True    54
5            C       False    89
6            D       False   100
7            D        True   656

print (df.dtypes)
federalState    object
hasParking        bool
Size             int64
dtype: object
```

For find missing values use:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['federalState','hasParking'])['Size'].unstack().unstack().reset_index(name='val')
print (df1)
   hasParking federalState    val
0       False            A  154.0
1       False            B  191.0
2       False            C    NaN
3       False            D  100.0
4        True            A  531.0
5        True            B  725.0
6        True            C   54.0
7        True            D  656.0

a = df1.loc[df1['val'].isnull(), ['federalState','hasParking']]
print (a)
  federalState  hasParking
2            C       False
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I insert the new line now?

Comment: I solved it with `df_new = df1.fillna(0)`. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to search within each lable of `"federalState"` column that whether there are some missing values.

To find elements that do not have the same unique values, you can first do `groupby` and then check unique elements in the `hasParking` column with `nunique()`.

```
df.groupby("federalState")["hasParking"].nunique()
federalState
A    2
B    2
C    1
D    2
Name: hasParking, dtype: int64
```

To check existence of a particular element in a group, you can try

```
df.groupby("federalState")["hasParking"].apply(lambda g: g.isin([False]).any())

federalState
A     True
B     True
C    False    # does not contain False
D     True
Name: hasParking, dtype: bool
```